# WSO2 Class Mediator - Is it possible to give more complex properties?

Tags: class, wso2, mediator

Example From the docs here:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Class+Mediator

```
            <class name="samples.mediators.SimpleClassMediator">
                <property name="variable1" value="10"/>
                <property name="variable2" value="5"/>
            </class>
```

What I would like to do:

```
            <class name="samples.mediators.SimpleClassMediator">
                <property name="variable1" value="10"/>
                <property name="variable2">
                    <list>                            
                        <foo>bar</foo>
                        <abc>def</abc>
                        <!-- up to 20 more props here -->
                    </list>
                </property>
            </class>
```

I'm willing to do dirty tricks to enable this if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set such a complex value to class mediator properties directly. But you can read any property from within the class mediator. For example see this.

```
<property name="variable2">            
   <list>                                                            
       <foo>bar</foo>                                                            
       <abc>def</abc>                                                
   </list>         
</property>         
<class name="org.wso2.ClassMediator"></class>
```

Inside class mediator, you can read the property like this.

```
OMElement ss = (OMElement) mc.getProperty("variable2");
```